# Signal handling function + not ignoring SIGINT

Tags: c, signals, posix

I have to write a program to emulate the bash shell. The relevant parts of the program are here. The program terminates on reception of EOF (not shown). One of the  different features to implement is not to terminate the program when CTRL-C is pressed. The program should just print a new command prompt again if SIGINT is recieved. I have a handler function which changes a global variable to end the current loop iteration, and the an outer loop which will then change it again to re-enter the inside loop. However, the program is still quitting when I press CTRL-C. Why is this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

void SIGINT_handler(int signum);

static volatile sig_atomic_t endflag = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    while(1){
        endflag = 0;

        while(!endflag){

                  struct sigaction action;

                  action.sa_handler = &SIGINT_handler;
                  action.sa_flags = 0;

                  if((sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask) == -1)||(sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL) == -1)){
                           perror("Failed to set SIGINT handler");
                           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                 }
         }
    }

    return 0;
}

void SIGINT_handler(int signo){

    if(signo == SIGINT){
        endflag = 1;
    }
    fflush(stdout);

}
```

Comment: The code looks more or less OK. Do you get any warnings during compilation? Which OS, which compiler are you using?

Comment: Flushing `stdout` from a signal handle might not be a good idea. Also I doubt the the global flag needs to defined `volatile`.

Comment: You need to post OS and compiler, this is working on a Mac with gcc and clang.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and gcc compiler. No warnings during compilation.

Comment: Works here as expected on a Debian old-stable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to register the signal Handler function in main function

put

(void) signal(SIGINT,SIGINT_handler);

right after it enter main function

Try This

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

   (void) signal(SIGINT,SIGINT_handler);  

while(1){
    endflag = 0;

    while(!endflag){

              struct sigaction action;

              action.sa_handler = &SIGINT_handler;
              action.sa_flags = 0;

              if((sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask) == -1)||(sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL) == -1)){
                       perror("Failed to set SIGINT handler");
                       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
     }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The call to `sigaction()` also registers a signal handler.